# How can I save ArrayList<String> in savedInstanceState

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView in my Activity and I'm currently working on implementing long-click selection of items to select items to be deleted. So far, everything is working.

I store selected items' tags in an ArrayList of String objects. However, when I change the screen orientation, the selection disappears. So I'd like to save the ArrayList in savedInstanceState to restore the selections.

Since the usual savedInstanceState is a Bundle object, I've looked at the documentation for Bundle at [1]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html.

I've noticed the following method that I believe is what I'm looking for but I don't quite understand it.

```
putParcelableArrayList(String key, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)
```

I've also seen that `String` does not extend Parcelable. So how would I use the above method with `ArrayList<String>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putStringArrayList(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList)

Comment: LOL, it seems like I didn't look hard enough. This will surely work but putSerializable("myKey", (Serializable)myarraylist) is also working. But that's stupid when there's an obviously better straightforward solution to it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidHeisnam `putSerializable` is less efficient, you should use `putStringArrayList`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using putStringArrayList now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
putStringArrayList (String key, ArrayList<String> value)
```

method